# How to disable sound when background image in Windows 10 changes

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, system-sounds

I have a theme with several background images in Windows 10. The background image automatically changes every x minutes. That's fine, but at the same time a sound is played. How can I disable this sound?

Answer (score 0):

Go to   `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization`, click on `Sounds`, choose `Windows Change Theme` (or its Windows 10 equivalent) from `Program Events` and change its sound to (None) from `Sounds` list.

Comment: The ```Windows Change Theme``` didn't have a sound, so it seems to be something else causing this :(

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the Speaker icon and click "Open Volume Mixer". See which applications are listed there. If none are listed (except the default ones), keep the mixer window open and watch for some time, until the sound is played

Alternately, you should be able to track this using Process Monitor... looking for .wav/.mp3 and probably other sounds files. Check out [How To Find Which Program Is Making Sounds In The Background?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-application-making-sounds-in-background/)